# "node build.js" fails when trying to install grunt-sass

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, centos, node-sass

I'm trying to switch from grunt-contrib-sass to grunt-sass, but I'm running into build errors related to node-sass inside the grunt wrapper module. So far I've upgraded node from 0.10.40 to 0.12.7 and switched to Python 2.7 in order to bypass a few other others, but this is what remains:

```
$ npm install

> node-sass@1.0.3 install /var/www/html/example.com/www/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node build.js

child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
make: Entering directory `/var/www/html/example.com/www/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build'
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/binding.o
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/binding.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/var/www/html/example.com/www/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-274.18.1.el5.centos.plus
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/html/example.com/www/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.18-274.18.1.el5.centos.plus
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@1.0.3 install: `node build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@1.0.3 install script 'node build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/example.com/www/npm-debug.log
```

Additional version info:

```
$ node -v
v0.12.7

$ node -v
v0.12.7

$ npm -v
2.11.3

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.11 (Final)
```

I'm a bit out of my depth on troubleshooting Node.js compatibility problems. While this is on a shared dev environment, I'm willing to try just about anything short of massive global change like upgrading the OS.

Update: I've since solved this by manually removing node-sass and node-gyp from the local node_modules folder. After that running npm install ran without errors. I think those modules were leftover from earlier attempts (before upgrading node.js and Python, most likely).